# How to remove operating systems and bios starting screen to restore hardware to when it was bought

Tags: linux, boot, installation, operating-systems

I have installed loads of different operating systems (windows, manjaro, artix, popos, 2 ubuntu systems) on the same computer for trying different things out and I'm not exactly sure where everything is installed. I want to remove all of these to start over from when I first had to install windows when I built my PC. Is there a simple step to wipe the computer like this? I don't want anything left over. I have already backed up all important files.

Comment: No need to try to remove BIOS. You need that for any OS. Use a bootable USB key from your main host OS, delete all partitions, and then install the main OS. That should work fine.

Comment: If you still have the Windows partitions, do [Reset](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html) after deleting all other partitions except UEFI.

Comment: @John Okay. What I meant by "removing bios" is I currently have somthing called grub 2 which makes it so that I have to press a button when I start my computer, otherwise it fails to load any os. I mean I want this gone, and return to the normal selection screen (bootloader?)

Comment: Just leave BIOS firmware level as it is is what I meant and then remove partitions. Once done and the prime OS is running you should be able to update BIOS and return to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinstall Windows from scratch. When you are given the option to choose a disk for installation, delete all the viewable partitions, and select Create New. Windows format the entire disk with a default partition table.

You seem to be well versed in how to install a OS, so I'll just leave these links.

Download the Windows ISO: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Download Rufus: https://rufus.ie/